# C# program that uses Microsoft Word interop

Tags: c#, ms-word

Word document: `word.doc`

```
One

Two

three
```

C# program that uses Microsoft Word interop

```
 using System;
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

 class Program
 {
   static void Main()
 {
    // Open a doc file.
    Application application = new Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // Write the word.
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
    }
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
  }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
Word 1 = One
Word 2 =
Word 3 = Two
Word 4 =
Word 5 = three
Word 6 =
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: this seems to be working  - what is the problem?

Comment: I guess your problem is why The output shows 6 words while there are only three words in document.If I'm right then it's because there is a enter after each word. You can simply ignore it by comparing `document.Words[i].Text`with Empty and Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - added another counter for the `real` words

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open a doc file.
            Application application = new Application();
            Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\temp\\word.doc");

            // Loop through all words in the document.

            int k = 1;

            int count = document.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                // Write the word.
                string text = document.Words[i].Text.Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", k, text);
                    k++;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            // Close word.
            application.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: also did a `Trim()` when we get the text var set